# Which lifecycle method is called after popBackStack on visible fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a single activity that opens fragments into it. Those fragments have transactions into one another. For instance, the activity contains 3 fragments (Fragment 1, Fragment 2, Fragment 3). Fragment 1 opens Fragment 2 and Fragment 2 opens Fragment 3. On back pressed, `popBackStack()` called. However, none of the lifecycle methods are called on new visible fragment such as `viewWillAppear()` in iOS. With which method can I detect that fragment is visible?

I have already tried `onResume()`, `getUserVisibleHint()` and `onAttach()`.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

@Override
    public boolean getUserVisibleHint() {
        return super.getUserVisibleHint();
    }

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

None of them are called. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The **onResume()** method should be called.

When you add a fragment to your activity, you need to add the transaction to the backstack so that it is included in the back navigation stack.

Here is a sample code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, yourFragment).addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```